# How can I always round down to the closest 10 whole number?

Tags: coldfusion, logic

So, I have a query that returns a number of records. And on my results page I display a line that says: Results 1 to 10 out of **30+** results are shown below.

The 30+ number I get by doing this:

```
<!--- round to the nearest ten --->
<cfset totalfoundRounded = Round(myquery.recordcount/ 10) * 10>
```

This works great if my recordcount is for example 34 or less. Or 24 or less, basically as soon as it gets over 5, my code rounds up. So even if there are only 18 records, it will say 20+ records found.

I have been scratching my head on how to get this logic to work, so that it always rounds down to the nearest 10, even if it's 18, or 19.

I tried using int() but that didn't work, it only works on decimal places.

So, is there a function in coldfusion, or some technique I'm missing to get this to work? I have been unable to find anything searching, and math is not my strong point :(

Thank you very much for any suggestions!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this?

```
<cfset totalfoundRounded = Int(myquery.recordcount/ 10) * 10>
```

Comment: I could have sworn I tried this, and it didn't work, but now this works! Maybe I missed something. Thank you very much! This does the trick!

Answer (score 5):

What do you want it to say when it's less than 10? 0+? You can probably do `number - (number % 10)`. This will always round down to the nearest multiple of 10.

Comment: That is a very good point! It was easy to overcome that though, I just wrapped the "+" part in an if statement. If totalfoundRounded is GTE 11, show it, otherwise hide it. :) thank you!

Comment: Btw, I don't really understand your original suggestion. What does % 10 do in coldfusion? And how is it different from Daniel's suggestion?

Comment: @Jennifer - He is using [modulus 10](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09d55-7ffc.html) to force the value to round down. By deducting that remainder, the result is the closest number divisible by ten ie 0, 10, 20, 30, etcetera. Modulus is a handy operator. Plug in a few values and test it yourself. See how it works.

Comment: @Leigh oh very cool. Thank you for that link, I hadn't seen that. I found http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions-pt0_14.html when I was searching. I wonder what the difference is in performance between the above solution and this one. Is there a way to test that?

Comment: Any performance benefits one solution has over the other would be pretty negligible.

Comment: @Jennifer - It is doubtful there is a measurable difference. Not unless you are performing the operation thousands of times in a single page, and possibly not even then. That said, you could create a crude test for your own edification. Throw each operation in a loop, run it a few thousand times and check the times.

Comment: @Leigh oh well it runs once on the page so I think I'll be safe :) thank you so much for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
 function Roundupdollars(amt) { 

    roundedAmt = amt * 100
    roundedAmt = Round(roundedAmt)
    roundedAmt = roundedAmt / 100
    return roundedAmt;
}
```

Comment: I wanted to round up and this solution seems to fit the "bill". See what I did there? ;) Just a side note, this does not answer the OP but I'm glad you posted this anyway.